# Angular 2 creating models vs working with json objects on the fly?

Tags: rest, angular, typescript, single-page-application

when interacting with a rest api using Angular 2. Is it worth creating typescript classes for each object (eg. employee, company, project, user ...). the other option is getting json object and working with it on the fly ?

Comment: Seems primarily opinion-based: It really depends of your needs.

Answer (score 2):

i suggest using models because :

1. your code will be more readable for yourself after a while coming back to change it, every one else also can easily understand what you've done
2. making changes in project will be more easily for example obj[0] does not have any special meaning but obj['username'] is more obvious
3. you will get intellinsense in you IDE
4. you can put logic in model for example so your controller will be more thin

   ```
   name: string
   age: number

   sayInfo(): string {
     return `name is ${this.name} and age is ${this.age}`
   }
   ```

   generally managing you app will be without headache (or at least less headache) :D

   just remember that fat models thin controllers

don't forget that passing more than five arguments to a function is not a good practice use an object instead for example :

```
constructor(file) {
  this.id = file['id']
  this.fileName = file['fileName']
  this.extention = file['extention']
  this.fileSize = file['fileSize']
  this.permission = file['permission']
  this.description = file['description']
  this.password = file['password']
  this.isFolder = file['isFolder']
  this.parent = file['parent']
  this.banStat = file['banStat']
  this.tinyLink = file['tinyLink']
  }
  getName(): string {
    return `${this.fileName}${(this.isFolder) ? '' : '.'}${this.extention}`
  }
  getIcon(): string {
    return this.isFolder ? 'fa-folder' : 'fa-music'
  }
```