# Calling a class in angular 2 gave me Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript

I created the following class `items-class.ts`:

```
export class ItemsClass {
    constructor(public name:string, public desc:string, public stat:string){}
}
```

And I want to use it in a component called `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemsClass } from './items-class';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  list:ItemsClass = new ItemsClass('Product 1', 'Electronics', 'Sold Out');
}
```

Now I want to display the item in an html template of the `app.component.html`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a class="btn btn-success">New Recipe</a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
    {{list.name}}
    </ul>
    {{list.desc}} | {{list.stat}} 
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is that I am getting this error:

> Module build failed: Error:
>   C:/Users/gis-dataasst/Desktop/test2/src/app/app.component.ts (9,21):
>   Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.)
>       at _checkDiagnostics (C:\Users...src\loader.js:145:15)
>       at C:\Users...\src\loader.js:172:17
>   @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 14:0-47  @ ./src/main.ts  @ multi main

Comment: Don't you need to create the fields (that you have given in the constructor) and assign them in the constructor?

Comment: @echonax what do you mean ? And what is web worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class fields aren't set

```
export class ItemsClass {
    name: string;
    desc: string;
    stat: string;
    constructor(public name:string, public desc:string, public stat:string){
      this.name = name;
      this.desc = desc;
      this.stat = stat;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. But according to a tutorial, he used the same class of mine and no errors shown.

Comment: @droidnation Which tutorial?

Comment: on udemy. he used the same class that I had on my question with no errors

Comment: @droidnation hmm, can't say anything without seeing it :/

Comment: take a look in second part of my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723684/angular-2-creating-models-vs-working-with-json-objects-on-the-fly/41725537#41725537)

Comment: @BardiaRastin I looked, what is the conclusion here?

Comment: @echonax use a object in your constructor then you can make new items in a more thin way and also order of parameters will not be important